# How to bypass a request when it takes too long?

Tags: python, timeout

I have a python library which must be fast enough for online application. If a particular request (function call) takes too long, I want to just bypass this request with an empty result returned.

The function looks like the following:

```
def fast_function(text):

    result = mylibrary.process(text)
    ...
```

If the mylibrary.process spend time more than a threshold limit, i.e. 100 milliseconds, I want to bypass this request and proceed to process the next 'text'.

What's the normal way to handle this? Is this a normal scenario? My application can afford to bypass a very small number of requests like this, if it takes too long.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a signal timer. As an example:

```
import signal

def took_too_long():
    raise TimeoutError

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, took_too_long)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.1)      # 0.1 seconds
try:
    result = mylibrary.process(text)
    signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0)    # success, reset to 0 to disable the timer
except TimeoutError:
    # took too long, do something
```

You'll have to experiment to see if this does or does not add too much overhead.

Comment: does this work in Windows? got `AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'` Error. As i searched in google for the answer i came across this Stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545002/python-standard-lib-signal-attributeerror-module-signal-has-no-attribute 
which indicates that `SIGALRM` doesn't work in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a timeout to your function.

One way to implement it is to use a timeout decorator which will throw an exception if the function runs for more than the defined timeout. In order to pass to the next operation you can catch the exception thrown by the timeout.

Install this one for example: `pip install timeout-decorator`

```
import timeout_decorator

@timeout_decorator.timeout(5) # timeout of 5 seconds
def fast_function(text):
    result = mylibrary.process(text)
```

Comment: can I set a limit of 50 milliseconds? Is it @timeout_decator_timeout(0.05)?

Comment: @marlon: Read the fine [usage information](https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/).

Comment: What should it return when time outs? What' the value of 'result' when timeout?

Comment: It raises exception. You can define which exception will be thrown, for example: `@timeout_decorator.timeout(5, timeout_exception=StopIteration`

Comment: ...and if you don't specify what exception to throw, the default's a `timeout_decorator.TimeoutError`.

Comment: Can it return an empty 'result' list, instead of raising exception. I don't want to terminate the program, just want to bypass this request in this function call.

Comment: As I mentioned in my response, you can invoke the function inside a `try` block and catch the exception inside the `except` block.

Comment: You mean invoke the function 'process()' or 'fast_function' in try block? or both are ok?

Comment: Invoke `fast_function` inside try block

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you so it might be useful of others as well.